# JSX - Copy a folder to target - ExtendScript

Tags: photoshop-script, jsx

I am trying to copy a selected folder to a defined target.

```
function importLabs(selected) {
    if(selected = "labAuto") {
        //Open Folder dialog box
       var myLab=Folder.selectDialog("Import");   
       myLab.copy ("~/Desktop/In here");
   }
}
```

Can't figure this one out. Am I using the wrong function .copy()?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no copy method for Folder.

You will need to create your destination folder first then copy each file.
If you would like to copy sub-folders as well then you need to do it recursively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use system bash

app.system(your bash command);

and calling the bash command cp -r or rsync